# PHP variable scope issue with mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I am still learning PHP and I'm trying to get around this error I'm getting. 
As per this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) my code is correct, but this is my code and this is the error i'm receiving:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("IP","username","passowrd","dbname");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

function get_demos(){
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM demos");
    if(!$result)
    {
        die("Invalid query ".mysqli_error($con));
    }
    return $result;
}

get_demos();
```

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /home/content/83/11483383/html/php/db.php on line 10
>
> Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given
>   in /home/content/83/11483383/html/php/db.php on line 13 Invalid query

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Pass your DB connection to your function.

Comment: use `function get_demos($con){}` and `get_demos($con);`

Answer (score 2):

You should try like,

```
$con = mysqli_connect("IP","username","passowrd","dbname");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

function get_demos($con){
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM demos");
    if(!$result)
    {
        die("Invalid query ".mysqli_error($con));
    }
    return $result;
}

get_demos($con);
```

Comment: But I want to be able to call the get_demos function from another php file where I wouldn't have the $con variable there. Any my main target is having a lot of functions that call different queries by having the $con variable global and defined to all of them.

Answer (score 2):

You are not declaring that a variable `$con` is already set.

Try this one

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
    mysqli_select_db($con, 'databse_name_here') or die ('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error()); 


function get_demos($con){
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users");
    if(!$result)
    {
        die("Invalid query ".mysqli_error($con));
    }
    return $result;
}

get_demos($con);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass your connection to your function. if you don't want to do it every time you can use singleton pattern to always have it in scope.

```
class DBCon {

private static $_instance = null;

 private function __construct() {
    $_instance = mysqli_connect("IP","username","passowrd","dbname");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
 }

 public static function get() {
   if(is_null(self::$_instance)) {
      self::$_instance = new DBCon();
   }
   return self::$_instance;
 }
}
```

and use it in your code :

```
function get_demos(){
    $result = mysqli_query(DBCon::get(),"SELECT * FROM demos");
    if(!$result)
    {
        die("Invalid query ".mysqli_error(DBCon::get()));
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: `new Singleton()`, what's this? :)

Answer (score -1):

I figured out the solution after putting the question:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("IP","username","passowrd","dbname");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

function get_demos(){
    global $con;
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM demos");
    if(!$result)
    {
        die("Invalid query ".mysqli_error($con));
    }
    return $result;
}

get_demos();
```

By adding global $con.

Comment: This is very-very bad practice, and this thread has same already.